# PHP script stops suddenly without any error

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script that downloads files with direct link from a remote server that I own. Sometimes large files (~500-600 MB) and sometimes small files (~50-100 MB).

Some code from the script:

```
$links[0]="file_1";
$links[0]="file_2";
$links[0]="file_3";

for($i=0;$i<count($links);$i++){

    $file_link=download_file($links[$i]); //this function downloads the file with curl and returns the path to the downloaded file in local server
    echo "Download complete";
    rename($file_link,"some other_path/..."); //this moves the downloaded file to some other location
    echo "Downloaded file moved";
    echo "Download complete";

}
```

My problem is if I download large file and run the script from web browser, it takes upto 5-10 minutes to complete and the script echos upto "Download complete" then it dies completely. I always find that the file that was being downloaded before the script dies is 100% downloaded.

On the other hand if I download small files like 50-100MB from web browser or run the script from command shell this problem does not occur at all and the script completes fully.

I am using my own VPS for this and do not have any time limit in the server. There is no fatal error or memory overload problem.

I also used `ssh2_sftp` to copy files from the remote server. But same problem when I run from web browser. It always downloads the file, executes the next line and then dies! Very strange!

What should I do to get over this problem?

Comment: Have you checked your web server's error logs?

Comment: Just out of topic, sorry, but I couldn't resist: I remember times, when "640KB should be enough for everyone". And now, 50-100 MB are "small files".

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you can download larger files, you will have to make sure that there is:

1. enough memory available for php
2. the maximum execution time limit is set high enough.

Judging from what you said about ssh2_sftp (i assume you are running it via php) your problem is the 2nd one. Check your error(-logs) to find if that truly is your error. If so you simply increase the maximum execution time in your settings/php.ini and that should fix it.

Note: I would encourage you not to let PHP handle these large files. Call some program (via `system()` or `exec()`) that will do the download for you as PHP still has garbage collection issues.

Comment: Could you explain in what files I should search for error messages? Checked apache error.log, ssl_error_log - no error messages. Is possible that Apache is restarting without leaving any messages?